# Performance: Postgres (Read-Committed) vs MySQL (Read-Uncommitted)

Tags: mysql, performance, postgresql

I have a workload that involves very frequent writes and reads. It is very performance sensitive, but not accuracy-sensitive. Hence, to maximize performance and minimize locking-delays, my plan was to issue all the reads using [Read-Uncommitted transaction isolation level](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/2/10/database-isolation-levels-and-their-effects-on-performance-a.html), on a Postgres database.

However, I started reading up a little on this topic, and realized that [Postgres treats Read-Uncommitted exactly the same way as Read-Committed](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-set-transaction.html).

MySQL does offer Read-Uncommitted functionality, which led me to believe that it might be a superior option for my performance needs. However, I came across another source which claims that [snapshotting isolates the readers from the effects of the writer until the writer commits... readers do not block the writer, and the writer does not block readers, so concurrent performance is excellent.](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/papers/concurrency/concurrency.pdf)

I'm aware that there are many performance differences between Postgres and MySQL, and I don't want to take this discussion off on a tangent. Specifically for the case of having multiple reads/writes, and using of Read-Uncommitted transactions in order to minimize locking delays, how does Postgres compare to MySQL in this particular scenario? Is the absence of true Read-Uncommitted functionality in Postgres a significant liability? Or does their snapshotting functionality work sufficiently well in eliminating locking overhead?

Comment: Install both and test.

Comment: It depends a lot on the workload, too, and you've been extremely vague about that. Personally I'd be surprised if read uncommitted had a significant performance benefit unless maybe you're using MyISAM tables ... in which case I hope you don't really need that data.

Comment: Single thread doing inserts?  Or multiple?  Single row inserted at a time?  Or multiple?  Reads are "point queries"?  Or table scans?  Or something in between?  Using auto_increment?  Inserting into same spot in table?  Reading where writing is happening?  All in the same table?